# How can I add "and" between multiple categories assigned to an entry?

Tags: templating

I have some entries that have more than one category assigned to them (under the same category group).  For example, Entry X might be assigned to Category A and Category D.   How do I get it to print `"Category A **and** Category B"` instead of `Category A Category B"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the categories of the entry, add and if it's not the last loop index, like so:

```
{% for category in  entry.categoryFieldHandle %}
 {{category.title}} {{ loop.last ? '': 'and '}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will work, certainly, but thanks to the way Craft works behind the scenes there is a more compact and elegant solution:

```
{{ entry.categoryFieldHandle|join(' and ') }}
```

### Why this works

The Entry's category field (accessed via `entry.categoryFieldHandle`) returns an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/ElementCriteriaModel), which implements [PHP's ArrayAccess interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

In plain English, this means that we can treat the ElementCriteriaModel as an array.

The ElementCriteriaModel returns a collection of [CategoryModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/CategoryModel) objects, each of which implements [a `__toString` method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) (returning the Category title). This effectively means we can treat the object as a string.

The above features mean that we can pass our ElementCriteriaModel directly to [the Twig `join` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/filters/join.html), and it will concatenate the Category titles using the "glue" string " and ".